# How do I diff the outputs of two commands?

Tags: bash, shell, diff, command-substitution

How can I use the `diff` command to compare 2 commands' outputs?

Does something like this exist?

```
diff  ($cat /etc/passwd) ($cut -f2/etc/passwd)
```

Comment: Of course, if one of the commands is really a `cat` with a single file argument, there's no obvious reason not to use that filename as one of the arguments to `diff`.

Comment: same question on stackoverflow with 250+ votes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800202/diff-output-from-two-programs-without-temporary-files

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use *process substitution*:

```
diff <(cat /etc/passwd) <(cut -f2 /etc/passwd)
```

`<(...)` is called process substitution.  It converts the output of a command into a file-like object that `diff` can read from.

While process substitution is not POSIX, it is supported by bash, ksh, and zsh.

Answer (score 9):

**Difference between 2 commands output :-**

`$ diff <(command1) <(command2)`

**Difference between command output and file :-**

`$ diff <(command) filename`

**Difference between 2 files :-**

`$ diff file1 file2`

e.g. `$ diff <(mount) <(cat /proc/mounts)`